# Highlight all data in a HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table, spreadsheet

Is there a way to do a selection highlight over all elements in a HTML Table?

I want to be able to have data displayed in a tabular form, and the user to be able to click a button to select the relevant data to copy and paste into the spreadsheet of their choosing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function selectAll(parentNode) {
    var sel;
    // IE
    if (document.selection) {
        sel = document.body.createTextRange();
        sel.moveToElementText(parentNode);
        sel.select();
    } else {
        sel = document.createRange();
        sel.setStartBefore(parentNode);
        sel.setEndAfter(parentNode);
        window.getSelection().addRange(sel);
    }
}

selectAll(document.getElementById('myTable'));
```

Test it out [here](http://jsbin.com/ijase).

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote an abstraction for the API to select data, I wrote the following comments. You might find the various URLs (which I cited in my comments) useful.

> This interface isn't based on a W3C
>   standard. Instead it's based on de
>   facto interfaces from various
>   browsers. It represents the object
>   that's returned when you invoke the
>   javascript window.getSelection()
>   method as described at
>   http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html
>
> The MS IE version of this interface is
>   the type of the "selection" object in
>   the Microsoft API which can be found
>   via
>   http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&q=html+and+dhtml+reference
>
> However this interface is based more
>   on the Mozilla API (instead of the MS
>   IE API). The Mozilla interface can be
>   found at
>   http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/content/base/public/nsISelection.idl
>   and
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection

If you're using a Javascript library like jquery, that might hide/abstract the browser-specific differences for you and give you a unified API.

Comment: How about removing the extraneous text and posting your links as, uh, links?

Answer (score 0):

Since most browsers already provide this functionality by letting the user select the text manually, why not provide the user with a link to download the data in Excel-compatible format, such as CSV? This is a more robust solution if you ever get enough data that you have to page, for example.